# value withFilter not a member of java.util.list

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

```
for {
  bucket: Terms.Bucket <- topLevelBuckets
  aggResult = AggResult(bucket.getKeyAsString, bucket.getDocCount,
    bucket.getAggregations.get("total_usage").asInstanceOf[Sum].getValue)
} yield aggResult
```

}

```
case class AggResult(bucketKey: String, bucketCount: Long, bucketValue: Double)
```

//here i want to return an List of AggResult but  it's showing me above error

```
/* Error:(113, 35) value withFilter is not a member of
java.util.List[org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.Terms.Bucket]
for {
  bucket: Terms.Bucket <-  topLevelBuckets
*/
```

/*
this works fine but returning an array
*/

```
def extractAggResults_(client: TcpClient): Array[AggResult] = {

    val nestingAggregation = client.execute(aggQuery).await

    val topLevelBuckets = nestingAggregation.aggregations.termsResult("by_users").getBuckets
    topLevelBuckets.toArray() map(bucket =>  AggResult(bucket.asInstanceOf[Terms.Bucket].getKeyAsString, bucket.asInstanceOf[Terms.Bucket].getDocCount, bucket.asInstanceOf[Terms.Bucket].getAggregations.get("total_usage").asInstanceOf[Sum].getValue))
  }
```

Comment: for-comprehension translates into flatMap/map and withFilter and then you could use only monaidic types with it, just convert the java.util.List to the scala.collections.immutable.List

Comment: for(bucket <-  topLevelBuckets.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.List[Terms.Bucket]])yield  {
      AggResult(bucket.getKeyAsString,bucket.getDocCount,bucket.getAggregations.get("total_usage").asInstanceOf[Sum].getValue)
    } // i tried this but it's not working

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List
 at BigginSight$.extractAggResults(BigginSight.scala:105)
 at BigginSight$.delayedEndpoint$BigginSight$1(BigginSight.scala:97)
 at BigginSight$delayedInit$body.apply(BigginSight.scala:10)
 at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
 at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)

Comment: you can't cast it to the scala List as it's a java.util one... Please look at this Java Conversions API:
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html

Comment: Have you tried moving the `AggResult` constructor call in the `yield` section? My guess is that you're trying to emit a collection of `AggResult`s

Comment: //i tried this for (
      bucket: Terms.Bucket <- topLevelBuckets
      ) yield AggResult(bucket.getKeyAsString, bucket.getDocCount,
      bucket.getAggregations.get("total_usage").asInstanceOf[Sum].getValue)

Comment: but its still show me error as : Error:(110, 31) value withFilter is not a member of java.util.List[org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.Terms.Bucket]
      bucket: Terms.Bucket <- topLevelBuckets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that JavaConversions (linked in the comment) is deprecated.

Use

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

for {
  bucket <- topLevelBuckets.asScala
} yield AggResult(bucket.getKeyAsString, bucket.getDocCount,
    bucket.getAggregations.get("total_usage").asInstanceOf[Sum].getValue)
```

If you need a Java `List` to pass to other methods, call `.asJava` on the result.

`asJava` and `asScala` are cheap operations; they just create simple adapter objects and don't copy all elements, as converting to Scala `List` would require.